# Android - Center text in DialogFrame

Tags: android, dialog, dialogfragment

How can I center the dialog_more_information in the following Code?. Is it necessary to use a custom view?

Thanks in advance!.

This is how I call it >

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.more_information:
        MoreInformationDialogFragment mDialog = new MoreInformationDialogFragment();
        mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);

        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the MoreInformationDialogFragment class >

```
public class MoreInformationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_more_information)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_visit_moma, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.somesite.org");
                   Intent SomeSite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                   startActivity(SomeSite);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Cancel
                   setResult(RESULT_CANCELED); // is this really needed?
               }
           });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do that:

```
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
return dialog;
```

Comment: It hangs the app by giving the following error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setGravity(int)' on a null object